# Not working Windows hosts file (for "localhost" name) in Parallels Desktop 16

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, localhost, hosts, parallels

I am using Parallels Desktop 16 on my Macbook Pro 15 (MacOs 10.15.7)
I am installing the free "Legacy version of Microsoft Edge on Windows 10" in Parallels Desktop 16. But I cannot redirect "*localhost*" use the hosts file. Everything was saved successfully, but does not work if execute "ping localhost".
At the same time, names other than "*localhost*" work correctly.
You can see the details in the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pymIi.jpg)

Comment: In your Windows 10 Guest, you need to open Notepad with Run as Administrator to edit the Hosts File and save it.  Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I did it with administrator rights.
But this did not help exactly for the "localhost".
You can see the details in the attached screenshot.